# How to add pagination in API

Tags: api, pagination

I want to know how to add pagination in APIs for enhanced data retrieval most specifically the youtube API!

I didn't try out anything so far as it's a new concept towards me!

Answer (score -1):

What i personally do usually is one of two things,

1. (the most preferred way for me) I create more than one API Token. every X requests i dynamically change the API that executes the request., then it avoids throttlings.
2. When requesting or sending a large amount of requests, you can stop dynamically every X time.

Comment: Kindly guide me through the process please!